# Custom, Sequence-Based ID Generator Hibernate 6 Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-6.x

**I had recently Migrated Hibernate from 5 to 6**

But facing issues with **LongType** which is deprecated in Hibernate 6

**Here is my implementation in Hibernate 5**

```java
public class StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {
 
    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER = "valuePrefix";
    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT = "";
    private String valuePrefix;
 
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER = "numberFormat";
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "%d";
    private String numberFormat;
 
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
            Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return valuePrefix + String.format(numberFormat, super.generate(session, object));
    }
 
    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params,
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
        super.configure(LongType.INSTANCE, params, serviceRegistry);
        valuePrefix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER,
                params, VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT);
        numberFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER,
                params, NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT);
    }
 
}
```

Since in Hibernate 6 -> org.hibernate.type.LongType is deprecated I am getting Error

**how to Implement a Custom, Sequence-Based ID Generator ??**

Comment: super.configure(LongType.INSTANCE, params, serviceRegistry);
LongType.INSTANCE return Type

Answer (score 7):

After checking javadocs https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/BasicTypeRegistry.html , i tried with this and it worked :

```
super.configure(new TypeConfiguration().getBasicTypeRegistry().getRegisteredType(Long.class), params, serviceRegistry);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate 6 the recommended way to implement a generator of this sort is to implement `BeforeExecutionGenerator`.

Comment: **Thank you** @gavin-king , I was able to fix it with a alternative `IdentifierGenerator`

Comment: Hi @NAVEENNAVEEN, Can you update the sample so that it will be useful to others